# Android XmlPullParser trouble

Tags: java, android, xml, xmlpullparser

I am having trouble fetching a specific value in an XML value using Android XMLPullParser. Here is a snippet of the XML file containing the information I need,

```
<parameters applicable-location="point1">
<temperature type="apparent" units="Fahrenheit" time-layout="k-p1h-n1-1">
<value>50</value>
</temperature>
<temperature type="dew point" units="Fahrenheit" time-layout="k-p1h-n1-1">
<value>33</value>
</temperature>
```

I am new to parsing to XML, but I need to retrieve the

```
<value>
```

of the:

```
<temperature type="apparent" units="Fahrenheit" time-layout="k-p1h-n1-1">
```

Now to me I would just do something like this:

```
if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("temperature") {

   xpp.next(); //To bring the parser to that value tag

   if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("value") {

      weather_apparenttemp.setText(xpp.getName());
   }
}
```

But it is not working and I feel I am missing or doing something wrong :( any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("temperature") {
if (xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "type").equals("apparent")){
    xpp.next(); //To bring the parser to that value tag
    if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("value") {
        weather_apparenttemp.setText(xpp.getName());
    }
}
```

This is for retrieve the tag name `<value>` inside the temperature typed as apparent. If you want to retrieve the value, advance the xpp with `xpp.next()` inside the second condition and get the text `xpp.getText()`.